# Inverse Fourier transform of scaled and shifted tanh function

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a function in frequency where I want to perform an inverse Fourier transform,
$$F(\omega)=\tanh(a(\omega-b))$$

where I define the FT relations as $F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dte^{i\omega t}f(t)$ and $f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tfrac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega t}F(\omega)$.

From [this post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/fourier-transform-of-hyperbolic-tangent.887956/), we can say that there is a Fourier transform pair
$$\tanh(\omega) \leftrightarrow \dfrac{t}{2}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi t}{2}$$

Then using the scaling and shifting properties $F(\omega-\alpha) \to f(t)e^{-i\alpha t}$ and $F(\omega/\alpha) \to |\alpha| f(\alpha t)$ (are they correct?) we deduce that
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[ \tanh(a(\omega-b)) \right] = 
|\tfrac{2}{a}|\tfrac{t}{2} e^{-ibt}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi at}{2}$$

Is this the correct way to deal with scaling and shifting properties? If not, is there a particular order in which they are considered?

**Edit:** Are there any good online references where I can find tables of these kinds of non-trivial Fourier transform pairs? e.g. [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/) is one famous example but they don't cover FTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's do a quick derivation

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{F\left(a[\omega-b]\right)\right\} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F\left(a[\omega-b]\right)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega$$

and make the following substitutions (assuming $a>0$ to avoid the hassles with the absolute values):

$$\begin{align*}\omega'&=a(\omega -b) & \implies \omega = \dfrac{\omega'}{a}+b\\
\\d\omega' &= a d\omega &\implies d\omega = \dfrac{d\omega'}{a}
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{F\left(a[\omega-b]\right)\right\} &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F\left(a[\omega-b]\right)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F\left(\omega'\right)e^{-j\left(\frac{\omega'}{a}+b\right) t}d\omega'\\
\\
&= \dfrac{e^{-jbt}}{a}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F\left(\omega'\right)e^{-j\omega'\frac{t}{a}}d\omega'\\
\\
&= \dfrac{e^{-jbt}}{a}f\left(\dfrac{t}{a}\right)\\
\\
\end{align*}$$

Assuming this transform pair is correct

$$\tanh(\omega) \leftrightarrow \dfrac{t}{2}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi t}{2}$$

then your desired transform pair is

$$\tanh(a[\omega-b]) \leftrightarrow \dfrac{e^{-jbt}}{|a|}\dfrac{t}{2a}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi t}{2a}$$

Comment: I've marked this as correct, even though the transform pair is incorrect. I misinterpreted the details in the link, so it should be $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\tanh(\omega)] = -\tfrac{i}{2}\mathrm{csch}(\pi t/2)$... whereas $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathrm{sech}^2(\omega)] = \tfrac{t}{2}\mathrm{csch}(\pi t/2)$.

Comment: Yeah, the pair didn't look right: a purely real and odd function should inverse transform to a purely imaginary and odd function.  Hence my use of the phrase "Assuming this transform pair is correct"

Comment: I just looked up the pair in Bracewell's book: $\tanh(\pi x) \leftrightarrow -i \mathrm{csch}(\pi s)$.  Bracewell uses $e^{-2\pi i s x}$ as the forward kernel and $e^{2\pi i x s}$ as ithe inverse kernel, so there's a scaling difference compared with what you found.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $F(\omega-\alpha) \to f(t)e^{\LARGE{\color{blue}{i\alpha t}}}$.

So
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[ \tanh(a(\omega-b)) \right] =\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[ \tanh(a\omega-ab) \right] \\
= \large |\tfrac{1}{a}|\tfrac{t}{2a} e^{it\frac{ab}{a}}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi t}{2a}
= |\tfrac{1}{a}|\tfrac{t}{2a} e^{ibt}\mathrm{csch}\dfrac{\pi t}{2a}.$$

My tip: if you insist on using properties, do the $x$-translation first, followed by the scaling. For instance, let $g(\omega)=\tanh(\omega-ab)$ and $h(\omega)=g(a\omega)=\tanh(a\omega-ab)=\tanh(a(\omega-b))$.

Comment: The sign of the exponent in the Fourier kernel is actually arbitrary.  As long as OP is consistent with the forward transform having one sign and the inverse transform having the opposite sign, he should be OK.  I agree though, normally the inverse transform does not use the negative sign.  OP did provide the definitions to use though.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks.